# sql select record with lowest value of the two

Tags: sql, postgresql

Despite my internet searching, I've not found a solution to what I think is a simple SQL problem.

I have a simple table as such:

```
zip   | location | transit
------------------------
10001 |    1     |  5
10001 |    2     |  2
```

This table of course has a large number of zip codes, but I'd like to make s simple query by zip code and instead of returning all rows with the zip, return only a single row (with all 3 columns), that contains the lowest transit value.

I've been playing with the aggregate function min(), but haven't gotten it right.

Using Postgres SQL DB 9.6

Thanks!

Comment: Can there be more than one row for a zip with the same transit? If yes, would you like to show all rows, should there be more than one with the lowest transit? Or just one? If just one, any criteria  to chose that one or is a random one just fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ORDER BY` along with [`LIMIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/queries-limit.html) :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
WHERE t.zipcode = ?
ORDER BY t.transit
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
select * from table where zip = ‘10001’ order by transit limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (zip) t.*
from t
order by zip, transit;
```

This is usually the most efficient method in Postgres, particularly with an index on `(zip, transit)`.

Of course if you have only one zip code that you care about, then `where`/`order by`/`limit` is also totally reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you also want to return the `location` value associated with the minimum `transit` value, then here is one possible solution using an `inner join`:

```
select t.*
from
    yourtable t inner join 
    (select u.zip, min(u.transit) as mt from yourtable u group by u.zip) v
    on t.zip = v.zip and t.transit = v.mt
```

Change all references to `yourtable` to the name of your table.